# jquery mobile history back

Tags: jquery-mobile

The page i use js to show and hide some elements.but there is problem when i use browser back.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div class="step1">
       step1 content...
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nextBtn">next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="step2" style="display:none">
       step2 content...
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="okBtn">next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="step3" style="display:none">
       step3 content...
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="goBtn">next</a>
    </div>
    <script>
    some script...
    $('.nextBtn').click(function(){
        ok = do something...
        if(ok){
          $('.step1').hide();
          $('.step2').show();
        }
    });
    $('.okBtn').click(function(){
        ok = do something...
        if(ok){
          $('.step2').hide();
          $('.step3').show();
        }
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

but when i use browser back button.there a problem. I mean when 'step2' is showing,i click back button,i want to go 'step1' is show.

Comment: you want to `.step1` to be visible when you go back to the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `.step1` to be visible when you load the page, here's the code.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function () {
 $('div.step1').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use https://github.com/browserstate/History.js
to manipulate the history of your browser